# python custom password hasher error

Tags: python, django, password-hash, honeypot, django-custom-user

hye . i cannot import my new custom password hasher and i still cannot figure it out why .

the error :

```
ImportError at /admin/

No module named 'honeywordHasher.hashers.MyHoneywordHasherdjango'; 'honeywordHasher.hashers' is not a package
```

i already did install honeywordHasher in INSTALLED_APPS and i have the **init**.py inside the honeywordHasher file.

directory :

```
C:.
├───checkout
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───templates
│   └───__pycache__
├───contact
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───templates
│   └───__pycache__
├───custom_user
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
├───honeywordHasher
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
├───profiles
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───templates
│   │   └───accounts
│   └───__pycache__
├───register
│   ├───migrations
│   ├───templates
│   │   └───accounts
│   └───__pycache__
├───sqlite
├───tryFOUR
│   └───__pycache__
└───__pycache__
```

settings.py :

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    'honeywordHasher.hashers.MyHoneywordHasher'
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.Argon2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher',
]
```

i already create hashers.py and also the honeyword generation in honeywordgen.py . i still get this error . can someone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed out the comma after your custom hasher. It should be:

```
'honeywordHasher.hashers.MyHoneywordHasher',
```

Without the comma, Python [concatenates](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation) the string with the one on the next line to form `'honeywordHasher.hashers.MyHoneywordHasherdjango.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher'`, which causes the import error.